# After the ISS which other artificial satellites are the best candidates to try to resolve in a telescope?

Tags: artificial-satellite, observation

> This question was asked on the initiative of the user @uhoh [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44300/can-the-transit-of-satellite-in-front-of-sun-be-visible-in-10-inch-telescope/44312).

I have a Sky-Watcher 10 inch Dobson telescope, equiped with a proper solar filter. Last year, I wanted to observe some satellites using the website [CalSky](https://www.calsky.com/) (btw, does anyone know other alternative since the website is down now?), but I never had enough time to do that. I remember just that the largest satellites were about 2˝ in angular size.

But the website is now down, so I can't check this experimentally: can I actually see the 2 arc-seconds large satellite, transiting the Sun? I know that many people have already observed the ISS and this wouldn't be such problem to do, but I am interested about actual satellites (not space stations). The theoretical angular resolution of such Dobson is around 1˝, but can it detect a 2˝ satellite transiting the Sun? I doubt about this because the satellites are pretty fast (except the geostationary ones) and the theoretical resolution applies to dark background, not to the dark objects. If it can't be seen using our own eyes, can it be detected using a cheap planetary camera?

Comment: 1/30th of the diameter of Venus transiting the Sun is certainly not something that can be done with just any telescope.

Comment: Any suggestions?